# Unrecognized characters in DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I opened up a Northwind database (northwind.sqlite3) using DB Browser for SQLite (Version 3.9.1).

[image: img1]

For some product names, I couldn't get the right names displayed no matter what I did, including:

- I changed new line characters options
- I changed Preferences options
- I checked the outputted csv using Excel and Notepad with different encoding

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Still couldn't figure out how to properly show the characters...Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(ProductName) FROM Products WHERE ProductID = 23`?

Comment: @CL. It's 54756E6E6272F664. Thanks

Comment: F6 is the CP1252 encoding of ö.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be either that data have been added to the database in an incompatible encoding (e.g., pasting data from Microsoft products into a UTF-8 database can do this) or that the DB Browser isn't displaying the data in the correct encoding.  To fix the former problem you may have to edit the data, or possibly change the database encoding.  You can't change the encoding of a SQLite database on the fly, so you would have to export the data and import them into a new database with the encoding that is actually used.  If it's just a DB Browser display issue, right-click on the table header and choose the option to change the display encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the response @rd_nielsen! I'm trying to change the encoding by right clicking on the header ProductName. Do you have any suggestions for the encoding I should use?

Comment: cp1252 at a guess, especially if you're on Windows or the data came from Windows.